# Which dependencies do I have to include in a Maven Apache Storm Project?

Tags: maven, dependencies, syntax-error, apache-storm

I am pretty new to Apache Storm and Maven projects, so I tried to follow this "tutorial" (which from my point of view is not a tutorial at all):

http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Creating-a-new-Storm-project.html

There is a huge pom.xml referenced (https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.1.1/examples/storm-starter/pom.xml) which shall be used as basis for a new project. I tried to figure out what to copy into my project pom.xml. So I decided to start with the apache core dependency first. My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>StormTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>            
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                    <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                    <mainClass>${storm.topology}</mainClass>
                    <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <finalName>StormTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT_dep</finalName>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>de.arphi.bi.WordCountTopology</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>log4j2.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

This even works when it is about runing maven and building / packaging a jar. The outcome are two jar files (a small one without dependencies and a bigger one with dependencies). I cannot run the smaller one because it says "main manifest not found". But I can run the bigger one by executing the following command:

storm -jar StormTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT_dep.jar

Actually the runs on my locally installed apache storm 1.1.1 (I have some System.out.printlns ...) but I get an exception:

```
2018-01-02 21:38:31,864 main ERROR Unable to create file C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\Bi\apache-storm-1.1.1\logs/access-web-${sys:daemon.name}.log java.io.IOException: Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalizeWithPrefix0(Native Method)
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalizeWithPrefix(WinNTFileSystem.java:451)
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:422)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.makeParentDirs(FileUtils.java:134)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:573)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:554)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:112)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:155)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:131)        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:60)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:952)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:892)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:884)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:508)        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:232)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:244)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:122)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at org.apache.storm.topology.BasicBoltExecutor.<clinit>(BasicBoltExecutor.java:28)
        at org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.setBolt(TopologyBuilder.java:215)
        at de.arphi.bi.WordCountTopology.main(WordCountTopology.java:22)
```

It says something about the syntax for creating a directory is wrong. And I know that it is about logging. I played arroung with different other dependencies (log4j, slf4j) and tried ecen to exclude dependecies without any success. I cannot get rid of this error.

Any ideas? I think that I am missing a dependency or that I have to exclude some parts of my pom.xml. But since I am not an Maven expert it is really hard for me to figure out what I have to adapt here.

Comment: it looks more like a configuration issue with storm? the placeholder "sys:daemon.name" seems to be unknown or not replaced. Did you run it from git bash or a cmd prompt? and in the correct directory? The docs mention a local mode: http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.1/Local-mode.html - I'm not a storm user so I don't know. But it doesnt look maven or build related

Answer (score 0):

I agree that storm-starter has gotten pretty big, and we should maybe have more of a minimal example.

First you should set the storm-core dependency to "provided" scope. When you deploy the topology to Storm, your jar will use the storm-core jar present in the Storm installation, so you shouldn't also put it in your fat jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>      
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When your topology runs on Storm, it will use the Log4j2 configuration in the log4j2/worker.xml file in your Storm installation. You shouldn't include your own log4j2.xml. If you need to set specific log levels, you can either modify worker.xml or use the CLI as described at http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.1/dynamic-log-level-settings.html.

Other than that your pom looks fine. I don't know why you have exec-maven-plugin in there (Edit: I see it's also in storm-starter, I think it's a leftover from when it was possible to run storm-starter in local mode. You shouldn't need it), and I might replace maven-assembly-plugin with the shade plugin, but I'd expect your topology to work regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Stig Rohde Døssing. Finally I found the origin for my exception base on your hint regarding the log4j2/worker.xml. The issue was not in the worker.xml, but in the cluster.xml which is located in the same directory.

When reading my Exception shown here, you can see that Java complains about creating a system path ("access-web-${sys:daemon.name}.log"). I found the placeholder sys:daemon.name in the cluster.xml and replaced it with something static like "access-web-mysysdaemonname.log". That fixed the issue. I have no idea why this placeholder could not be resolved by the system while there was no trouble with other placeholders.

Thanks for the hints. Topic can be closed.